# How to track conversion from “new visitor” to “returning visitor” in Google Analytics?

Tags: google, analytics, visitors

I own a site, and I want to know how many of my "new visitors" are being converted into "returning visitors" after visiting my site.

Not how often users visit my site, recency or anything like that, but how many of new visitors come back, after stumbling upon my site.

Do any of you out there know how to track this using Google Analytics?

Answer (score 1):

Set the reporting date range to the entire history of your site, including today.  Then go to Audience -> Behaviour -> Frequency & Recency.

Count of visits = 1 is the number of visitors who came to your site for the first time - this will match your new visitor metric.

Count of visits = 2 is the number of your visitors who returned to the site.  This is the number who 'converted' and came back after their first visit.

Answer (score 0):

When you go (in Google analytics) to: **Sources-->All Traffic** you'll be able to view:
 "*Visits*" vs. "*% New Visits*", for example:

[image]

Comment: Thanks but it wasn't quite, what I'm looking for. As i wrote, I'd like to know how many of my new visitors (firt-time visitors) come back after they've visited my site 1 time. Thus the conversion rate from new visitors to returning visitors.

Comment: In that case - you can implement a cookies mechanism that will help you to do it. shouldn't be too difficult.

Comment: Thanks! Do you know of any online ressources, that can help you with that? Cause my cookie-coding skills are non existent.

Comment: I heard about ODesk - but I don't have any experience with that website. TMHO: learn Javascript - it's fun! ;)